# How do I test a website using XAMPP with a "https://" URL?

Tags: xampp

I have a file in htdocs and run it on my IDE, but the url of my file is "C://" but the book from which I am learning from requires the URL to be "https://" how do  do I change the URL? (I am using XAMPP)

The file is in .php so I am unsure of how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is **not** a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**. And no, it's not about `php.ini`. It's not about PHP at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try like this

ServerName/
Directory/
File

```
http://localhost/your_folderName/fileName.php
```

Comment: The problem was that I was not typing http://localhost/your_folderName/fileName.php into the URL. What I was doing was running my file from Sublime Text which I didn't realize wouldn't run the code on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your url is C:// it means that the website is not actually a website. It's just a file in your C-drive. A HTTPS:// is an uploaded website on the web. Let's say that the website shows: C://xampp/htdocs/website.php/, the browser refers to your C-drive and then your xampp-file, then your htdocs-file and then your code. But a HTTPS means that its a website thats uploaded to an actual web server. HTTPS stands for hyper text transfer protocal secure and means that is an secure website that has been uploaded to a web server. C stands for C-drive wich is your main hard-disk

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the site as an `https://` domain if it has an SSL server. If it is on `C:`, it isn't actually hosted as a website, but you can buy a domain and port forward the server. However, you can access it locally at `http://127.0.0.1/path/to/file` if you have a server running (like `Apache` or `XAMPP`).

Comment: I was using XAMPP. My problem was running the code off of sublime text by pressing "control +  alt + v". This opened the file, but didn't run it on the server. I didn't know pressing "control +  alt + v" and typing the directory in the URL accomplished different things. But thank you anyway.